# Nginx proxy_pass through 2 servers and custom headers getting "lost"

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am having a problem with my Nginx configuration.

I have an Nginx server(A) that adds custom headers and then that proxy_passes to another server(B) which then proxy passes to my flask app(C) that reads the headers. If I go from `A -> C` the flask app can read the headers that are set but if I go through B (`A -> B -> C`) the headers seem to be removed.

Config

```
events {
    worker_connections 512;
}

http {
    # Server B
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:5001;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
    }

    # Server A
    server {
        listen 4999;
        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-User 'username';
        }
    }
}
```

Flask app running on `127.0.0.1:5000`

If I change the server A config to `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000` then the Flask app can see the `X-Forwarded-User` but if I go through server B the headers are "lost"

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This is not the exact configuration but is basically what it is like. It does compile and requests can go from `A -> B -> C` but the header is not present once it reaches C.

Comment: Did you verify that this config produces your problem?

Comment: if you [contact me](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik?tab=profile), we may be able to figure it out together, but as i explained in my answer below, the config you've shared with us here is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce the issue, sending the custom header `X-custom-header: custom` in my netcat server i get:

```sh
nc -l -vvv -p 5000
Listening on [0.0.0.0] (family 0, port 5000)
Connection from localhost 41368 received!
GET / HTTP/1.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:5000
Connection: close
X-Forwarded-User: username
User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
Accept: */*
X-custom-header: custom
```

(see? the X-custom-header is on the last line)

when i run this curl command:

`curl -H "X-custom-header: custom" http://127.0.0.1:4999/`

against an nginx server running this exact config:

```
events {
    worker_connections 512;
}

http {
    # Server B
    server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:5001;
        server_name 127.0.0.1;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000;
        }
    }

    # Server A
    server {
        listen 4999;
        server_name domain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-User 'username';
        }
    }
}
```

thus i can only assume that the problem is in the part of your config that you *isn't* showing us. (you said it yourself, it's not the real config you're showing us, but a replica. specifically, a replica that isn't showing the problem)

thus i have voted to close this question as "can not reproduce" - at least i can't.